# How to calculate custom degree based on the node label or other conditions?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a scenario where I need to calcula a custom degree between the first node (`:employee`) where it should only be incremented to another node when this node's label is `:natural` or `:relative`, but not when it is `:legal`.

Example:
[image]

The thing is I'm having trouble generating this `custom degree` property as I needed it.

So far I've tried playing with FOREACH and CASE but had no luck. The closest I got to getting some sort of calculated custom degree is this:

```
match p = (:employee)-[*5..5]-()
WITH distinct nodes(p) AS nodes
FOREACH(i IN RANGE(0, size(nodes)) |
    FOREACH(node IN [nodes[i]] |
        SET node.degree = i
))
return *
limit 1
```

But even this isn't right, as despite having 5 distinct nodes, I get `SIZE(nodes) = 6`, as the `:legal` node is accounted for twice for some reason.

Does anyone know how to achieve my goal within a single cypher query?

Also, if you know why the `:legal` node is account for twice, please let me know. I suspect it is because it has 2 `:natural` nodes related to it, but don't know the inner workings that make it appear twice.

**More context:**

`:employee` nodes are, well, employees of an organization

`:relative` nodes are relatives to an employee

`:natural` nodes are natural persons that may or may not be related to a `:legal`

`:legal` nodes are companies (legal persons) that may, or may not, be related to an `:employee`, `:relative`, `:natural` or another `:legal` on an `IS_PARTNER` relationship when, in real life, they are part of the board of directors or are shareholders of that company (`:legal`).

`custom degree` is what I aim to create and will define how close one node is to another given some conditions to this project (specified below).

All nodes have a `total_contracts` property that are the total amount of money received through contracts.

The objective is to find any employees with relationships to another node that has `total_contracts > 0` and are up to `custom degree <= 3`, as employees may be receiving money from external sources, when they shouldn't.

As for why I need this custom degree ignoring the distance when it is a `:legal` node, is because we threat companies as the same distance as the natural person that is a partner.

On the illustrated example above, the employee has a son, `DIEGO`, that is a shareholder of a company (`ALLURE`) and has 2 other business partners (`JOSE` and `ROSIEL`). When I ask what's the degree of the son to the employee, I should get `1`, as they are directly related; when I ask whats the degree of `JOSE` to the employee I should get `2`, as `JOSE` is related to `DIEGO` through `ALLURE` and we shouldn't increment the custom degree when it is a company, only when its a person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick with this type of graph is making sure we avoid paths that loop back to the same nodes (which is definitely going to happen quite a lot because you're using multiple relationships between nodes instead of just one...you may want to make sure this is necessary in your model).

The easiest way to do that is via [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_paths), as you can adjust the uniqueness of traversals so that nodes are unique in each path.

So for example, for a specific start node (let's say the :employee has `empId:1` just for the sake of mocking up a lookup of the node, we'll calculate a degree for all nodes within 5 hops of the starting node. The idea here is that we'll take the length of the path (the number of hops) - the number of :legal nodes in the path (by filtering the nodes in the path for just :legal nodes, then getting the size of that filtered list).

```
MATCH (e:employee {empId:1})
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(e, {minLevel:1, maxLevel:5, uniqueness:'NODE_PATH'}) YIELD path
WITH e, last(nodes(path)) as endNode, 
 length(path) - size([x in nodes(path) WHERE x:legal]) as customDegree
RETURN e, endNode, customDegree
```

Comment: This seems exactly what I needed. Ran a couple tests, will run a few more and will mark as accepted answer if everything goes alright. Didn't know about apoc, really liked it from what I read on the docs. As per the bi-directional relationships, I do need them, as a company is linked to a person and vice versa. Now, is there any way to add the `customDegree` property to each node on the path just so I can double check it is calculating correctly?

Comment: As for the bi-directional relationships, if a single IS_PARTNER relationship always implies its reciprocal relationship, then you don't need both, just one.

Comment: If you just need a check, just use `SET endNode.customDegree = customDegree` before your RETURN, but make sure you remove the property after you've confirmed it.

Comment: My test database consists of ~2.1M nodes when the actual db is ~21M nodes. I've run a few tests using the test db and when I run without limit, it never finishes (4h+). Is apoc procedures way slower than raw queries? If I run this https://gist.github.com/jlcd/6ccd5f1ad50f27c5c569e77b265b047a which would require some post processing to determine custom degrees, it takes around 10 minutes to finish.

Comment: jump on the chat if you have time please, the comments are way longer than they should be. With maxLevel: 5+ it takes a long time to process. 4- takes 14s or less. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177217/discussion-between-dmmd-and-inversefalcon

Comment: APOC can be tuned to use different types of uniqueness vs Cypher. Whether that's faster or not depends upon the uniqueness chosen and your graph data, it's not an across the board slower vs faster thing. Also be aware that usage of `shortestPath()`, when using unbound nodes (like `f` in your gist) is going to do a cartesian product against all nodes in your graph, then find the shortest path for each one.